# Retrieve Date from SQLite Android Studio java

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date, android-sqlite

I saved the current date in SQLite and then retrieve the date from SQLite but every time the result is zero where is the problem??

My code to get the current date is

```
 private String getDate() {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd / MM / yyy ");
        return mdformat.format(calendar.getTime());
 }
```

and my code to save into SQLite

```
           PrayDBHelper mDBHelper = new PrayDBHelper(PrayActivity.this);
           SQLiteDatabase db = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

           db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + prayEntry.TABLE_NAME + " " +prayEntry.DATE +  " VALUES " +
                     getDate());
```

my code to retrive date from SQLite DB

```
    dbConnection();
    Cursor cursor= db.query(prayEntry.TABLE_NAME,prayEntry.DATE,null,null, null,
            null,null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String date = (cursor.getString(0));// get Date
        labelDATE.setText(date);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never store dates in SQLite with a format different than `YYYY-MM-DD`.
Anything else than this format will cause you trouble when it comes to query, compare and sort by this date.
For your code, this statement (including parentheses around the column name which must exist in your code or an exception would be thrown, so I guess this is just a typo):

```
"INSERT INTO "+prayEntry.TABLE_NAME+" ("+prayEntry.DATE +") VALUES "+getDate()
```

will save `0` in the table because `getDate()` returns a value like: `19 / 12 / 2019` which is interpreted as integer divisions between the numbers 19, 12 and 2019 which result to `0`.
 
The reason is that you do not enclose the date inside single quotes, like:

```
"INSERT INTO "+prayEntry.TABLE_NAME+" ("+prayEntry.DATE +") VALUES '"+getDate()+"'"
```

But this is not the recommended way of doing insertions.
Use the method `insert()` and `ContentValues()` like this:

```
PrayDBHelper mDBHelper = new PrayDBHelper(PrayActivity.this);
SQLiteDatabase db = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(prayEntry.DATE, getDate());
db.insert(prayEntry.TABLE_NAME, cv);
db.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I beleieve that you issue is with the INSERT in that the value after the TABLE name, the column(s) into which data is to be placed should be within parenthesises. Also the VALUES themselves should each be within parenthesies and strings within values should be enclosed in single quotes, so instead of

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + prayEntry.TABLE_NAME + " " +prayEntry.DATE +  " VALUES " +
                 getDate());
```

You should be using :-

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + prayEntry.TABLE_NAME + "(" +prayEntry.DATE +  ") VALUES ('" +
                 getDate() + "'));
```

Saying that it you use the **insert** convenience method, this builds the correct SQL on your behalf. As such it is suggested that you use :-

```
PrayDBHelper mDBHelper = new PrayDBHelper(PrayActivity.this);
SQLiteDatabase db = mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(prayEntry.DATE,getDate());
db.insert(prayEntry.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
```

It is also reocmmended that you don't use column offsets directly when retrieving data but that instead you utilise the Cursor's getColumnIndex method to get the offset.

So instead of `String date = (cursor.getString(0));` you could use :-

```
String date = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(prayEntry.DATE)));
```

In regard to dates you may find it much easier if you store dates in a format that SQlite recognises e.g. YYYY-MM-DD (2019-01-01 for 1st Jan 2019), dates in such a format are directly sortable and allow them to be used directly by SQlite's date and time functions. As such it is suggested that you use `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")`.